# Check if a Base 64 image is blank or black

Tags: javascript, html, base64

I've been tasked with checking if an image captured from a webcam and encoded into base64 is either blank or black and I was wondering where to start?

Comment: What's exactly the difference between a blank and a black picture?

Comment: You haven't specified a language you're using (and like @ÁlvaroGonzález said, what blank means to you). But take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528299/get-pixel-color-of-base64-png-using-javascript) answer. I assume your problem will be solved by looking at pixel colours.